# Passing google login cookies from scrapy splash to selenium

Tags: selenium, google-signin, scrapy-splash

I want to sign in to my Google Account and enable a Google API and extract the developer's key. My main task is to automate this process.

Everyone knows that you can't log into the Google Account using an automated browser. I did manage to do that using scrapy splash.

```
import re
import time
import base64
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from selenium import webdriver


class GoogleScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'google_scraper'

script = """
function main(splash)
  splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)
  local url = splash.args.url
  local youtube_url = "https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com"
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(1))
    
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  local search_input = splash:select('.whsOnd.zHQkBf')
  search_input:send_text("xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com")
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  splash:runjs("document.getElementById('identifierNext').click()")
  splash:wait(5)
  
  local search_input = splash:select('.whsOnd.zHQkBf')
  search_input:send_text("xxxxxxxx")
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  splash:runjs("document.getElementById('passwordNext').click()")
  splash:wait(5)
  
  return {
            cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
            html = splash:html(),
            png = splash:png()
        }
end
"""

def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://accounts.google.com'
    yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint='execute', session_id="1", args={'lua_source': self.script})

def parse(self, response):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])

    with open('image.png', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(imgdata)
    cookies = response.data.get("cookies")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")

    for cookie in cookies:
        if "." in cookie["domain"][:1]:
            url = f"https://www{cookie['domain']}"
        else:
            url = f"https://{cookie['domain']}"

        driver.get(url)
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)

    driver.get("https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com")
    time.sleep(5)
```

In the parse function I'm trying to retrieve those cookies and add them to my chromedriver to bypass the login process so I can move ahead to enabling the API and extracting the key but I always face the login page in the chromedriver.

Your help would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using `pickle` to save cookies instead, just use any python console to save the cookies with this code

```py
import pickle
input('press enter when logged')
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('cookies.pkl'))
```

then you get the `cookies.pkl` file with google login data, import it in your code using:

```py
import pickle
cookies = pickle.load(open('cookies.pkl'))
for cookie in cookies:
  driver.add_cookies(cookie)
driver.refresh()
# rest of work here...
```

*refresh the driver to enable the cookies*

Comment: What I have tried is adding the cookies directly without storing them in a pickle file and they don't work. I always end up on the login page in the browser.